# LINQ-To-Sql Update - Performance Issues

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table which includes 230 columns and 12 million rows.

I need to update 123 fields of EACH row.

If I try to do it with LINQ-To-Sql, I get System.OutOfMemory Exception.

I know I don't get OutofMemory error if I disable object tracking.
But I think I cannot perform updates if I disable object tracking.

What is the best way to update them?

Comment: Will the values of the 123 fields be different for each row? Can they be calculated with some formula? In other words, can you do this operation with a single SQL UPDATE statement?

Comment: I assume you are setting the same data in each row, as you'll not be able to hold this many objects in memory?  The simple answer is to use a stored procedure, and drag this into your EDML file.

Comment: 230 columns sounds suspicious....

Comment: @Mitch - 230 columns that require the same data updated in 123 columns for all the records in the tables sounds even more sus...

Comment: Each row has different values for its columns. It is CALCULATED for each row.

Comment: Can we use the term "schema-smell" for this sort of situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is not a task suitable for LINQ-to-SQL, or frankly any ORM. You **do not** want to drag that much data *twice* over the network in that way; that should ideally be written in pure TSQL, perhaps using bulk insert / `SqlBulkCopy` to populate a separate table if you need to combine with data from other sources.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely suggest that you change the architecture, decouple the big table into several small ones and definitely avoid linq-to-sql for this amount of data.

Create the architecture in that way that you have classes for each entity on a business level that will call stored procedures of T-SQL queries to update the data on data access level.